# Не могу понять ошибку в коде поздравления

Tags: python

Пишу маме поздравление с 8 марта.

Не понимаю почему второй условный оператор (elif) не работает.

Язык: Python

```
name = input('Как тебя зовут? ')

poem1 = 'С 8 Марта поздравляю!'
poem2 = 'Счастья и любви желаю.'
poem3 = 'Пусть сбываются мечты,'
poem4 = 'И на сердце теплоты.'
poemes = '  '
poem5 = 'Пусть в душе бушует радость,'
poem6 = 'Чтоб была и в жизни сладость.'
poem7 = 'Дома был всегда уют,'
poem8 = 'Жизнь красива, как салют!'

sorry = 'Тебя я поздравляю тоже, но стих я писал своей любимой маме'

if name == 'Вика' or 'Витуся' or 'Виточка' or 'Виктория' or 'Викочка':
    print(poem1)
    print(poem2)
    print(poem3)
    print(poem4)
    print(poemes)
    print(poem5)
    print(poem6)
    print(poem7)
    print(poem8)

if name != 'Вика' or 'Витуся' or 'Виточка' or 'Виктория' or 'Викочка':
    print(sorry)
```

Comment: Саму ошибку выложите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ошибки нет, но когда я ввожу другое имя например: абраджульхадазамарат, то стих всё равно выводится хотя не должен

Comment: Классическая ошибка начинающих, смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант

```
name = input('Как вас зовут? ')

poem = '''
    С 8 Марта поздравляю!
    Счастья и любви желаю.
    Пусть сбываются мечты,
    И на сердце теплоты.

    Пусть в душе бушует радость,
    Чтоб была и в жизни сладость.
    Дома был всегда уют,
    Жизнь красива, как салют!
'''

sorry = 'Вас я поздравляю тоже, но стих я писал своей любимой маме.'

_listName = ['Вика', 'Витуся', 'Виточка', 'Виктория', 'Викочка', ]

if name in _listName:
    print(poem)
else:
    print(sorry)
```

Comment: Ну вы совсем код переделали. Тогда новичку надо бы объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input('Как тебя зовут? ')

poem1 = 'С 8 Марта поздравляю!'
poem2 = 'Счастья и любви желаю.'
poem3 = 'Пусть сбываются мечты,'
poem4 = 'И на сердце теплоты.'
poemes = '  '
poem5 = 'Пусть в душе бушует радость,'
poem6 = 'Чтоб была и в жизни сладость.'
poem7 = 'Дома был всегда уют,'
poem8 = 'Жизнь красива, как салют!'

sorry = 'Тебя я поздравляю тоже, но стих я писал своей любимой маме'

if name == 'Вика' or name == 'Витуся' or name == 'Виточка' or name == 'Виктория' or name == 'Викочка':
    print(poem1)
    print(poem2)
    print(poem3)
    print(poem4)
    print(poemes)
    print(poem5)
    print(poem6)
    print(poem7)
    print(poem8)

else:
    print(sorry)
```